# How to pronounce the partition relation

Tags: set-theory, terminology, infinitary-combinatorics

The *partition relation*

$$ \kappa \to (\alpha)^m_\lambda $$

says that for any $f:[\kappa]^m \to \lambda$, there is a $X\subseteq \kappa$ such that $f$ is constant on $[X]^m$ and the order type of $X$ is $\alpha$.

(My introduction to this notation was from Drake's book on large cardinals, but I believe that it comes from Erdős and Rado.)

My question: how do you pronounce this relation when reading it out loud (if there is a standard way)?

Comment: Not that something is missing from Andres' answer, but this might just be the record for shortest interval from posting an answer to accepting it (32 seconds!).

Comment: Wow, I didn't notice that. I just logged in to check, and there was the answer, with all of the information asked for, so of course I marked as accepted straight away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read it as "$\kappa$ arrows $\alpha$-$m$-$\lambda$", or some small variant of this, such as "$\kappa$ arrows $\alpha$ super $m$ sub $\lambda$". Nothing too enlightening. That this is indeed the suggested reading is indicated in section 8.2 (pg. 53) of the Erdős-Hajnal-Máté-Rado book, **Combinatorial set theory: Partition relations for cardinals**.

(The notation indeed comes from a paper by Erdős and Rado, but it was designed by Rado in the early 50s. My understanding is that Erdős would complain about it from time to time, in spite of its usefulness.)

Comment: I don't recall hearing Uncle Paul actually **complain** about the arrow notation, but he would explain it by saying "in human language, this means . . ."